# How can I build SpiderMonkey from source properly

Tags: spidermonkey

I want to embed SpiderMonkey in my c++ application. I downloaded latest mozilla firefox 78 from
[here](https://treeherder.mozilla.org/#/jobs?repo=mozilla-esr52&filter-searchStr=spidermonkey-sm-package) as instructed [from mozilla's official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/52) and follow this
[Build documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation). The build failed with this message

```
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/pject/PJS/mozjs 78.0.0/js/src/_build/_virtualenvs/init_py3/Scripts/python.exe': '/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/pject/PJS/mozjs 78.0.0/js/src/_build/_virtualenvs/init_py3/Scripts/python.exe'
```

So I tried copying whole python.exe to _virtualenvs/init_py3/Scripts/ but it give another error

I'm on Windows 10, using Cygwin and mingw for compilers

Comment: Are you sure you want the full SpiderMonkey interpreter? If you just want to embed JavaScript, consider [Duktape](https://duktape.org/) or [QuickJS](https://bellard.org/quickjs/)

Comment: @Botje does this support import and export?

Comment: QuickJS claims full support for modules. Duktape is "only" ES5, but you can transpile the modules away if you must.